# ncurses, direct console input, how to implement in vs17 without *.lib, *.dll, *.h - files?

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, static-libraries, lib

first of all: I am fairly new to the C- section. So please dont roast but rather help me understanding, if I got something wrong. Thank you in advance.

So...
I do have a big problem which doesn't seem to be found anywhere in the extend that I need it to be solved.

**My standpoint:** *I want to read and directly direct a keyboard- input to a specific function.* 
NCurses has been mentioned a hundredfold and I thought like: Well yes, that looks promising.

I find many tutorials on how to implement non-standard libraries into the VisualStudio environment, but all of them seem to require following files: *.dll, *.lib, *.h.

Seems legit. I also found, that *.a seems to be a "static library", so it seems I may be able to use the *.a instead of the *.lib files.

Now, when I go on and download the latest ncurses (6.1, ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/), I dont find any of the *.h and *.lib, nor *.dll files. In addition to that, I honestly dont even know, which of those files are crucial to implement for the most basic functions of ncurses.

No matter how long I search, either they show me a ncurses version, which has already "pre- built" *.lib- files, etc., or they explain it with the terminal/console (which I dont need nor understand, cause I use VS2017).

I hope you understand where I('m) s(t)uck at and hope that you can help me.
Also, if I asked this question although it already exists, I'm sorry, but I couldnt find any of this questioning in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

For GNU, you can use the termcaps for reading.
When you compile the file you have to link the libraries curse

Cmake:

```
add_executable(${NAME} ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${NAME} libft ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

Commande line:

```
gcc main.c -I header.h -lncurses
```

So maybe you have somewhere in vs a way to edit compilations flag. Here you have to add -lncurses has a compilation command flag.

If librairies still not found, maybe you have to install it

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```